Does this functional admit an absolute minimizer?
This is a close relative of the following problem.
Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded subdomain of $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary, and $f_i \in W^{1, \infty} (\Omega)$ a sequence of functions equibounded in $W^{1, \infty}$ norm - that is, there exists some $M > 0$ such that $\|f_i\|_{W^{1, \infty} (\Omega)} < M$ for each $i$.
Define the functional $L: W^{1, \infty} (\Omega) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$L(h) = \limsup_{i \to \infty} \|f_i - h\|_{L^\infty (\Omega)},$$
and write
$$L_{|U} (h) := \limsup_{i \to \infty} \|f_i - h\|_{L^\infty (U)}$$
for the restriction of the functional $L$ to an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$.
We say $f \in W^{1, \infty} (\Omega)$ is an absolute minimizer of $L$ if for every open ball $B$, and every $g \in W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$ such that $f = g$ on $\partial B$, we have
$$L_{|B} (f) \leq L_{|B} (g)$$
Question: Does the functional $L$ admit an absolute minimizer?

doesn’t  $\displaystyle f:=\frac12\big(\limsup_{i\to\infty}f_i + \liminf_{i\to\infty}f_i\big)$  work?

@PietroMajer I think that works so long as the sequence $f_i$ is regular enough - however, in general $f$ is discontinuous…

That said I have been trying to write a discontinuous counterexample for the past hour and have failed LOL

But by Morrey the $f_i$ are equilipschitz, so $f$ is Lipschitz too. And the uniform norm of the limsup is the limsup of the norms. I think you don't even need regularity of $\partial\Omega$, since everything is local

@Pietro Majer Yep you are right on all three counts… I will just have to check that it satisfies the absolute minimiser condition always. Thanks for your answers as usual!

I think everything is clear to you by now, anyway here are some elementary fact that seem relevant.

For an open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ iff the restrictions $f_{|B}$ to balls $B\subset \Omega$ are uniformly bounded and uniformly Lipschitz, the best Lipschitz  constant being $\|Df\|_{\infty,\Omega}$ .

As a consequence, for a bounded sequence $(f_i)_{i\ge0}\subset W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$, one has that $\displaystyle\sup_{i\ge0}f_i$, $\displaystyle\inf_{i\ge0}f_i$ and  $\displaystyle\limsup_{i\to\infty}f_i=\inf_{k\ge0}\sup_{i\ge k}f_i$ are in $\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. Moreover, the decreasing sequence $\sup_{i\ge k} f_i$ converges uniformly on every bounded set  $B\subset \Omega$ by the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem or by the Dini's monotone convergence theorem, so
$$\sup_{x\in B}\limsup_{i\to\infty}f_i(x)= \sup_{x\in B}\lim_{k\to\infty} \sup_{i\ge k} f_i(x)= \lim_{k\to\infty}  \sup_{x\in B} \sup_{i\ge k} f_i(x)=  $$$$=\lim_{k\to\infty}  \sup_{i\ge k}  \sup_{x\in B}f_i(x)=\limsup_{i\to\infty}  \sup_{x\in B}f_i(x).$$

For a sequence of real numbers $(a_i)_{i\ge0}$ and $b\in\mathbb R$,
$$\limsup_{i\to\infty}|a_i-b|= |\limsup_{i\to\infty}a_i-b|\vee |\liminf_{i\to\infty}a_i-b|  $$

In particular,  your  functional  just depends from $f^*:=\limsup_{i\to\infty}f_i$ and $f_*:=\liminf_{i\to\infty}f_i$  rather than on the whole sequence $(f_i)$, namely, for every $g$
$$L(g,B):=\limsup_{i\to\infty}\|f_i-g\|_{\infty,B}= \|f^*-g\|_{\infty,B}\vee \|f_*-g\|_{\infty,B} $$

If $\tilde f:=\frac12(f^*+f_*)$, $$ L(\tilde f,B)=\|\frac12(f^*-f_*)\|_{\infty,B}\le \frac12\|f^*-g\|_{\infty,B}+ \frac12\|f_*-g\|_{\infty,B} \le$$


$$\|f^*-g\|_{\infty,B}\vee \|f_*-g\|_{\infty,B}=L(g,B).$$

An absolute minimiser according to the above definition is not unique in general. For instance, for $n:=1$, $\Omega:=]0,1[$, suppose $f^*(t)=t$ and $f_*(t)=0$. Then $f^*$ is also an absolute minimiser: for every $B:=[a,b]\subset\Omega$ and for every $g$ such that $g(a)=a$ and $g(b)=b$,one has $L(f^*,B)=\|f^*-f_*\|_{\infty,B}=b\le\|f^*-g\|_{\infty,B}\vee\|f_*-g\|_{\infty,B}=F(g,B)$.


I... think some of these might be new even to me... very nice...
